# No module named .. while running Django tests with PyCharm

Tags: django, pycharm, django-testing

I have the following error when running Django's tests with PyCharm 4.5 `ImportError: No module named date_utils`.

Here is a short overview the project tree:

```
.
├── manage.py
├── settings.py
├── app1
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __init__.py            #Empty
├── utils
│   ├── __init__.py            #Empty
│   ├── date_utils.py
```

In `app1.models.py`, I do
from `utils.date_utils import my_wonderful_function`

I import both apps in my `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'grappelli',
    '...',
    'djcelery',
    'utils',
    'app1',
)
```

Please note that it is working well when using `manage.py test`.

Can you please help understanding why this is happening with PyCharm but not with manage.py ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. Problem was that PyCharm also have module named utils, and so the import was not using my module, but the PyCharm's one.

Comment: There is a patch on the JetBrains issues tracker. They say it will be resolved in version 4.5.3. But I am running that version and it is not resolve. I installed the patch and things seem to be working. Here is the URL: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16054#comment=27-1016339